# Backspace Tab in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I have block of code that I would like to move (2 space/1 tab) backwards.  I know I can select the whole block and hit tab to move it forward but how do I move the whole block backwards (to the the left)?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

There are two options:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Tab</kbd>

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>[</kbd> (on mac this is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+ <kbd>[</kbd>)

Answer (score 5):

In Window Os Simple Press

`Shift` + `Tab`

To Remove Back Space Tab In sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 0):

in **linux**,**windows**

It can be done with this command

Sublime Text,Vscode,Elipse,PhpStorm,Atom => **shift+tab**

Python IDLE => **Ctrl + [**